# Why are my juju relation hooks not running?

Tags: 12.04, juju

I'm trying to create a charm that can connect to rabbitmq. I've written an amqp-relation-joined, and an amqp-relation-changed. Neither of these scripts executes when I run `juju add-relation $mycharm rabbitmq-server`. In the logs, I'm seeing

```
...
==> <$HOME>/.juju/local/log/unit-rabbitmq-server-0.log <==
2014-03-04 20:43:48 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:523 no new charm event
2014-03-04 20:43:48 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:338 got relations change

==> <$HOME>/.juju/local/log/unit-flask-0.log <==
2014-03-04 20:43:48 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:523 no new charm event
2014-03-04 20:43:48 DEBUG juju.worker.uniter.filter filter.go:338 got relations 
...
```

I expect to see some sort of output from my hooks because I'm logging stuff.

In `amqp-relation-joined`:

```
echo "DOING AMQP STUFF"
juju-log "$JUJU_REMOTE_UNIT modified its settings"
juju-log "Relation settings:"
relation-get
juju-log "Relation members:"
relation-list
touch /var/i_was_here
```

In `amqp-relation-changed`:

```
echo "DOING AMQP STUFF"
juju-log "$JUJU_REMOTE_UNIT modified its settings"
juju-log "Relation settings:"
relation-get
juju-log "Relation members:"
relation-list
touch /var/i_was_also_here
```

When I ssh into the machine, I am not seeing either `/var/i_was_here` or `/var/i_was_also_here`

I am running juju on Ubuntu 12.04 in local mode.

**EDIT:**

The metadata.yml is

```
name: flask
summary: Flask is a lightweight "microframework" that is often used for simple apis
maintainer: Ubuntu <Ubuntu@ip-172-31-24-81.us-west-2.compute.internal>
description: |
  ...
categories:
  - misc
subordinate: false
provides:
  api:
    interface: http
requires:
  amqp:
    interface: rabbitmq
```

The charms that I'm using are rolled into a single repository at https://github.com/peterklipfel/firesuit/tree/master/charms

Comment: Can you add your charm metadata.yaml file to the post please. Or if you have it hosted on a public repository that would even be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the problem that I was having was that I was not backgrounding a process in the `start` hook. As such, the hook never completed and essentially froze the state of that service. I thought it was working because the api that I was setting up would respond. The process that froze it was a foreground uwsgi process.

However, `debug-hooks` was not running because the node was frozen. What I didn't realize is that the tmux session opens a *new* session for each hook. So the initial session will *not* have the capabilities shown in the documentation... Of course, the documentation says this, but my brain didn't pick it up.

Thanks to all the juju folks for helping me through that one.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with what you've posted. You should check to make sure your hooks are executable and also take a look at the `debug hooks` command:

https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/developer-debugging

Comment: I have been trying to make `juju debug-hooks` work for 2 days, and it seems to be almost completely broken. The tmux session opens, but none of the documentation works